# Swift 3/JSON - Como capturar Lista de objetos dentro de um objeto?

Tags: json, swift

Como eu acesso uma lista de objetos dentro de uma outra lista de objetos?
Consigo capturar esses objetos tranquilamente, mas estou tendo dificuldades de capturar objetos dentro dessa lista.
Eis o meu JSON:

[image: JSON]

Nesse caso eu quero ter acesso aos valores que estão dentro de "NOTAS" e "FALTAS" mas não estou tendo muito sucesso nisso...
Segue meu código:

```
 for item in resultado!{

    let newDisc = DisciplinasML()

    newDisc.codDisciplina = item["COD_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.desDisciplina = item["DES_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.desPeriodo = item["DES_PERIODO"]! as? String
    newDisc.medDisciplina = item["MEDIA_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.nomProfessor = item["NOM_PESSOA_PROF"]! as? String
    newDisc.perFaltas = item["PERCENTUAL_AULAS"]! as? String

       //Eu acho que não seja assim que se capture o valor
       for nota in (item["NOTAS"]! as! NSArray){

           //nota has no subscription members     
           print(nota["COD_AVALIACAO"] as String)

       }
        //Adiciono os itens na lista
        self.listDisciplinasWS.append(newDisc)
 }
```

Alguma dica? 
Agradeço toda ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar `NSArray` tente utilizar os tipos nativos do Swift, pois usando o `NSArray` o compilador não conseguirá inferir que o array contém dicionários dentro dele.

```
for item in resultado!{

    let newDisc = DisciplinasML()

    newDisc.codDisciplina = item["COD_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.desDisciplina = item["DES_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.desPeriodo = item["DES_PERIODO"]! as? String
    newDisc.medDisciplina = item["MEDIA_DISCIPLINA"]! as? String
    newDisc.nomProfessor = item["NOM_PESSOA_PROF"]! as? String
    newDisc.perFaltas = item["PERCENTUAL_AULAS"]! as? String

    // Modificação ocorre nessa parte do código
    for nota in (item["NOTAS"]! as! [[String:Any]]){

       //nota has no subscription members     
       print(nota["COD_AVALIACAO"] as! String)

    }

    self.listDisciplinasWS.append(newDisc)
}
```